# truncate tables or replace old data with new data using imp oracle utility

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I need import utility to remove old data then reinsert new data. How can I do that without using data pump?

The reason I can't use data pump is because I need to run this script on application server, I don't have the privilege to run this on database server. below is the script I'm currently trying to fix

```
imp < username >/< password >@//< host > fromuser=< schema > touser=< schema > file=exp_$TODAY.dmp  log=exp_import_$TODAY.log ignore=y
```

Comment: You can run data pump on a server other than the db server, your account just has to have permission on the data directory (the oracle db directory) that you reference in the data pump script.  Do you need the file locally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMP can't *truncate* tables prior to importing, so - you're out of luck here. If you could use the Data Pump Import, you could use the [TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10825/dp_import.htm) parameter set to `TRUNCATE` (which would remove existing data) or even `REPLACE` (which drops table, creates it and loads data). Ask the DBA to provide access to a directory you could use for importing purposes.

Alternatively, as it seems that you're importing *everything*, consider dropping the target user (with the *cascade* option) and then import its objects.

Or, if it isn't too complicated, create a script which would truncate tables, for example

```
SQL> select 'truncate table ' || tname ||';' from tab;

'TRUNCATETABLE'||TNAME||';'
----------------------------------------------
truncate table BONUS;
truncate table DEPT;
truncate table EMP;
truncate table SALGRADE;
truncate table WC;

SQL>
```

so you'd run those `TRUNCATE TABLE` statements prior to importing.

Note that - if there are foreign key constraints - they won't let you do it unless you disable them; as above, you could use SQL to create SQL for you:

```
SQL> select 'alter table ' || table_name || ' disable constraint ' || constraint_name ||';'
  2  from user_constraints
  3  where constraint_type = 'R';

'ALTERTABLE'||TABLE_NAME||'DISABLECONSTRAINT'||CONSTRAINT_NAME||';'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
alter table EMP disable constraint FK_DEPTNO;

SQL>
```

Comment: ... and that is one more reason Postgres is going to rule the database world! We'll live to see oracle die in ostracism!